# ttest mean differs from mean value in R

Tags: r, mean, t-test

I want to check whether the purchase intention of a product is affected by a label. I did a t-test
t.test(myfile$Purch_Int~myfile$Product) and got

mean in group 0 = 3.757

mean in group 1 = 3.883

but when I ask for the mean
myfile[Product== 1, mean(Purch_Int), by = Label] I get:

mean in group 0 = 3.938

mean in group 1 = 3.821

Why is there such a big difference?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What is the `Label` column that wasn't used in the `t.test()` function?

Comment: you have selected different groups.  In the t test you group by product.  In mean, you filter to product==1 then group by Label.  These should be expected to differ